# Does the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ mean the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ complete?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, real-numbers, complete-spaces

As far as I know, completeness is a property of topological vector space whose topology induced by a metric. While $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, generally speaking, a set, rather than a space. But mathematicians usually say $\mathbb{R}$ is complete (perhaps, with respect to the Euclidean metric $d_E$). Do they exactly mean the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is complete?

Furthermore, I read some textbooks regarding the proof of the completeness of real number line that are too complicated, [for example here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy_Sequence_Converges_on_Real_Number_Line). Can anyone provide me with a simple and clear proof in just a few lines?

Comment: That is not how this site works. If you find a specific proof that you are unable to follow, post it here, telling us exactly which passages you do not understand.

Comment: Those are two separate questions. Please post the second one separately, and at the very least mention which definition of $\mathbb R$ you're using.

Comment: Completeness is a property of metric spaces (or more generally uniform spaces). You don't require any linear structure on your space so the underlying field is irrelevant.

Comment: There are 2 concepts of completeness associated with $\Bbb R.$ One is order-completeness (Dedekind completeness):  Any non-empty subset with an upper bound ( lower bound) has a lub (has a glb). The other is the completeness of the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ on $\Bbb R:$ Any $d$-Cauchy sequence  converges (with respect to $d$) to a member of $\Bbb R.$  On $\Bbb R$ these 2 concepts are pretty much the same thing  but on other structures they are not.